# Why does the session return null?

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I can not write to a session variable.

This is my source code:

```
   public class CurrentUser
    {

        public static string UserName
        {
            get
            {
                if (HttpContext.Current.Session["UserName"] != null)
                    return (string)HttpContext.Current.Session["UserName"];
                else
                    return null;
            }

            set
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Session["UserName"] = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

I call this class for write:

```
public class SQLGetData
    {

        public UserDC LogIn()
        {

            UserDC userDC = new UserDC();


            CurrentUser.Id = 1;
            CurrentUser.UserName = "Admin"; 

            userDC.id = 1;
            userDC.UserName = "Admin";

            return userDC;
        }


    }
```

When I want to call (MasterPage.aspx):

```
Label1.Text = CurrentUser.Id + CurrentUser.UserName;
```

**RESULT:** CurrentUser.Id is **1** and CurrentUser.UserName is **NULL**.

Why is CurrentUser.UserName NULL?
How do I modify this public string UserName to write?

Comment: Try adding a debug line in set AFTER setting the value.  System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(CurrentUser.UserName);  If it works, writing to Session is not the issue.  It could be that a new session has been spawned.

Comment: Perhaps session cookie is lost? What context(s) setter and getter are called from?

Comment: I write to the Current.UserName in class SQLGetData and i read Current.UserName in MasterPage.aspx.

Comment: I edited my question. Check now please. Where is my problem?

Comment: Unsure how the above code works at all - I fail to see the where `CurrentUser` is instantiated, nor how you can even get `1` for `CurrentUser.Id`

Comment: Can you try using ToString() when returning value instead of (string) cast

Comment: Can you post the code for the `Id` property?  If it's working as you say, this may help to identify the problem.

Comment: What's happening in the `UserDC` class? Is it a similar definition to the `CurrentUser` class?

Answer (score 0):

From the code that you share, it is not possible to really help you as we can only try to guess what is happening.

I assume that your CurrentUser class has an Id property with a similar code as Username.
The Id property works as expected but not the username...this sounds really odds.

Can you share the full code of your class? or at least the code for the Id property?

Then it would also help to understand from where you call your SQLGetData class. How does the authentication works?

Answer (score 0):

My wisdom with these kind of session null scenarios says that - there are hidden errors occurring in your applications but not unearthed. any exception inside the code would kill the session and might continue with a new session so the values are null...

best approach, run your dev environment code in vs ide with debug --> exceptions menu, on all exception handlers and run through the application for several scenarios, eventually you would realize there are hidden errors starting from simple errors like convertToInt or similar reference errors, which cause session becomes null... But as I guessed things did not break at error in "error" page but found through above "DEBUG" with all exceptions ON option.

Hope it helps!
HydTechie

Answer (score -1):

You should first introduce the "UserName" to your Session by using

```
HttpContext.Current.Session.Add("UserName", value)
```

in your setter.

```
public class CurrentUser     
{          
 public static string UserName         
 {             
    get             
    {                 
      if (HttpContext.Current.Session["UserName"] != null)                     
         return (string)HttpContext.Current.Session["UserName"];
      else                     
         return null;             
    }              
    set             
    {                
      if (HttpContext.Current.Session["UserName"] == null)
         HttpContext.Current.Session.Add("UserName", value);
      else
         HttpContext.Current.Session["UserName"] = value;            
    }         
  }     
}
```

After doing that it should work as you wrote.

Comment: You shouldn't have to do this.  Creating new session variables works automatically when you write code like `Session["UserName"] = "test"`.